# How data from differen session is merged in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have built a shiny app on ubuntu server and share to working partners. For some reasons, I suspect that part of the data they keyin has lost, but I couldn't find concrete evidence to prove it.

Plase advise how data generated at different sessions can merge together. They do, do thay?

[image]

Comment: You can maybe use a reactive outside server.R or use global assignment operators `<<-` to make those available to all the users

Comment: you mean to expose the RDS (storing all the data) to all users?